# How to extract network traffic information using tshark?

Tags: wireshark, tshark

I need to analyze the wireless traffic occurring in Ch 1 of 802.11g. I have captured all the traffic logs using NETMON as test.cap file. 
Q: How can extract the information using tshark to suitable format so that it can be used for further post processing?

Comment: Which particular information do you want to extract?

Comment: I just want to plot the wireless activity during certain time period.

Comment: "Activity" as in "packets transmitted per second", "activity" as in "bytes transmitted per second", or some other measurement of activity?

Comment: Either bytes/s or packet/s is fine if it reflect the actual activity in Ch11. The thing is I am running experiment in CH14 with my own AP->STA setup. Though Ch14 and Ch11 is far apart looking at 802.11g waveform but still I want to confirm if sudden TP drop in Ch14 is not due to high user activity in Ch11. In Ch11 there are many AP operating. I have captured all the activity in Ch11 but in wireshark it shows only 802.11 in protocol. Thus if there is sudden TP drop in my experiment in Ch14, I just want to see there is high activity in Ch11 at same time.

Answer (score 0):

> I have captured all the activity in Ch11 but in wireshark it shows only 802.11 in protocol.

That usually means "the traffic is encrypted and Wireshark doesn't have enough information to decrypt it"; it *does* represent activity.

So if you're capturing on channel 11, an I/O graph in Wireshark, rather than anything extracted using TShark and further processed, should suffice to show the level of activity on that channel.  You'd only have to dissect it if you want to see what type of traffic, at a higher level, that activity is, but it sounds as if you just care about activity, no matter what the packets are.